# VPN in L2TP connect fail

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I have a problem with L2TP VPN. I used Ubuntu 18.04 and installed network-manager-l2tp, network-manager-l2tp-gnome, but I failed to connect company's L2TP VPN. The following is syslog.

```
Jul  1 18:13:24 linyong-PC charon: 12[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 4104919682 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
Jul  1 18:13:24 linyong-PC charon: 12[IKE] received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
Jul  1 18:13:24 linyong-PC NetworkManager[1077]: establishing connection 'dcbd7b48-3e65-4b14-92c7-f906f159cd70' failed
Jul  1 18:13:25 linyong-PC NetworkManager[1077]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
Jul  1 18:13:25 linyong-PC charon: 00[DMN] signal of type SIGINT received. Shutting down
Jul  1 18:13:25 linyong-PC nm-l2tp-service[23236]: g_dbus_method_invocation_take_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
Jul  1 18:13:25 linyong-PC NetworkManager[1077]: <info>  [1561976005.2076] vpn-connection[0x555810a8c810,dcbd7b48-3e65-4b14-92c7-f906f159cd70,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Jul  1 18:13:25 linyong-PC NetworkManager[1077]: <info>  [1561976005.2122] vpn-connection[0x555810a8c810,dcbd7b48-3e65-4b14-92c7-f906f159cd70,"VPN 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
Jul  1 18:13:25 linyong-PC NetworkManager[1077]: <warn>  [1561976005.2133] vpn-connection[0x555810a8c810,dcbd7b48-3e65-4b14-92c7-f906f159cd70,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: failed to connect: 'Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying'
```

I am able to connect the VPN in Windows 10, I don't know if I missed some config. What can I do?

Comment: Thanks to correct my statement.

Answer (score 0):

The VPN server is not accepting the strongSwan default proposals, so you need to enter Phase 1 & 2 algorithm proposals in NetworkManager-l2tp's IPsec configuration dialog box.

See the package's README file for Phase 1 & 2 Algorithms that Windows uses :

- https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/tree/1.2.10#example-workaround-for-3des-sha1-and-modp1024-broken-algorithms